# How can I apply this code for email validation to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I apply this code to JavaScript?

This code will check email address validation in PHP.
But i want to apply this code to JavaScript.

How can I do that?

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $strEmail = $_POST[email_send_value];
    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $strEmail))
    {
        // NOT OK //
    }
    else
    {
        // OK //
    }
?>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script>
    var email_var = document.getElementById("CheckEmail").value;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
</script>
```

Comment: Thats terrible for many reasons, E.g. it rejects any TLD with more than three letters ...

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)